# Oracle Help for Java integration in Swing application

Tags: java, swing, javahelp

I want to integrate Oracle Help for Java (ohj) in my Java Swing application to show its components in my custom window. Any ideas? I think there is no source code on the web.

Comment: The Oracle Help for Java release includes sample code, in particular ChoiceDemo.java and CSHDemo.java. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/doc.1111/e14149/ohjpg_intro.htm#BABIHFDF.

Comment: I saw these files but they show me only how to use it, not how to customize. For my project I need to remove some javahelp components from the GUI.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you, but you should edit the question to make it more specific. What exactly do you want to customize? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: For example I need to remove menubar & default buttons. Then I need to customize windows properties and insert new object.